# Apache SPARK zipWithUniqueID

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I need to generate unique ids for each of my tuple [ Equivalent to surrogate key generation in ETL dimension processing]

```
def attachLongSurrogateKeys[T: ClassTag](dim: RDD[T], nextSurrogateKey: Long): (RDD[(T, Long)], Long) = {
  val dimensionWithSK = dim.zipWithUniqueId.map { case (x, y) => (x, y + nextSurrogateKey) }
  val newSurrogateKey = dimensionWithSK.map { case (row, sk) => sk }.max
  (dimensionWithSK, newSurrogateKey)
}
```

I will be dealing with 4 billion rows. I'm slightly worried about the performance of line #3 where get the max of generated surrogate key..

Is there a better clean way to achieve the same ?